# Change the backgorund color according to mouse movement

Tags: javascript, html

is there a simple code in Html, javascript to change the complete backgroundcolor of the screen according to where the mouse is. The colors should fade to another, no hard interruption. Just a smoove transition.
thanks

Comment: What are you going to base the colors chosen on, exactly? The element hovered over, or somesuch? Some more detail would be great, including any code you already have, etc.

Answer (score 13):

You can listen to the mousemove event and do some logic calculations based on position and window size. How that logic should be is up to you, but I made a quick example for you (using jQuery):

```
var $win = $(window),
    w = 0,h = 0,
    rgb = [],
    getWidth = function() {
        w = $win.width();
        h = $win.height();
    };

$win.resize(getWidth).mousemove(function(e) {

    rgb = [
        Math.round(e.pageX/w * 255),
        Math.round(e.pageY/h * 255),
        150
    ];

    $(document.body).css('background','rgb('+rgb.join(',')+')');

}).resize();
```

The `rgb` array is the array where I store the RGB values that should be applied, and then I just change the values based on where the mouse position is.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/WV8jX/
    ​

Comment: Thanks a lot to Gothenburg. :)

Comment: I'm just getting started with jQuerry, I used to be pretty good at ActionScript 3.. I can't get this to work in my HTML page, I've got the above code under window.onload = function 
but it doesn't work, althgough i cleary see in your Demo that it does... 

What I am doing wrong...

Comment: Very simple, elegant solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You could set the event `onmouseover` on each element. For example you can set a function called `changeBackground(int code)`. In each element you set a code to know which color you want to set.

For example you could have the following:

```
<div name="myBackgroundDiv">
    <div onmouseover="changeBackground(1)"/>
    <div onmouseover="changeBackground(2)"/>
    <div onmouseover="changeBackground(3)"/>
</div>
```

and in `changeBackground` function you can specify to change the background color of "myBackgroundDiv" depending on the number passed.

You can review [this](http://www.htmlgoodies.com/beyond/javascript/article.php/3470771/Advanced-JavaScript-for-Web-Developers-onClick-and-onMouseOver.htm) and [this](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onmouseover.asp).

Best regards,